# How can I stop a Tag Helper from being used automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

For example: I want my `<form>` tag to render as-is. Instead it is auto-generating all the other goodies with it.

How do I turn off tag helpers for that one specific tag?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add a `!` before the tag name to prevent the tag helper from executing:

```
<!form method="post">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</!form>
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?#opting-out-of-individual-elements)

Answer (score 7):

You can remove a specific TagHelper from impacting a view by referencing its full type name, i.e.:

```
@removeTagHelper The.Full.TypeName.Of.The.TagHelper, TheAssemblyNameTheTagHelperExistsIn
```

Alternatively if you want to disable all TagHelpers in an assembly:

```
@removeTagHelper *, TheAssemblyNameTheTagHelperExistsIn
```

So to come full circle, if you want to disable all default MVC TagHelpers you can include the two lines:

```
@* This nukes ~/ resolution and ITagHelperComponents (things running on body/head), this is an auto-inclusion in every view *@
@removeTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor

@* These TagHelpers are typically included via a _ViewImports.cshtml. This nukes all of the MVC TagHelpers (environment, input with asp-for, etc.)*@
@removeTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: Thanks; This is useful information but not quite what i was looking for. I don't want to completely remove or disable a tag helper, i just want to "override" for a specific instance.

Comment: When you say for a specific instance, are you saying for a specific instance on a view?

Comment: @n-taylor-mullen say for example i have two form tags on a page and for just the one of them i dont want taghelper to activate but for the other one i do. (p.s. i cant get your username right in the mention)

Comment: Ah, ya that's not supported. The only way to have similar functionality is to separate your forms into different views and include TagHelpers separately