# How to prevent Tag Helper rendering and show it in html code tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I want to prevent the render tag `<partial>` using asp.net core helpers. My code is:

```html
<pre>
    <code class="language-html">
        <partial name="~/Breadcrumbs/BreadcrumbTemplate.cshtml" model="breadcrumbs" />
    </code>
</pre>
```

I need print exactly the same the code, without rendering. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i stop a Tag Helper automatically being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498990/how-can-i-stop-a-tag-helper-automatically-being-used)

Comment: I have tried that but not works for `<partial>`, like as: `<!partial name="~/Breadcrumbs/BreadcrumbTemplate.cshtml" model="breadcrumbs"/>`. The partial is rendered.

Comment: I just put the code you just typed into a View, the html of the page had `<partial .../>`.

Comment: Can you give me an example? please.

Comment: I just put _exactly_ what you typed into a view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mFoC.png The `<partial>` element is there, it didn't attempt to resolve any partial. How does this not work for you?

Comment: I get this [https://i.imgur.com/MZr01yC.png](https://i.imgur.com/MZr01yC.png). The `partial` tag is not rendered, but it is not printed in `code` tag.

Comment: Go look at the source code of the page, I bet it's there and the browser doesn't know how to display a `<partial>` element. You might also want to switch to a `<pre>` rather than `<code>`.

Comment: No code is generated at source code.

Comment: “No code is generated at source code.” – What does that even mean? Right click the page in the browser and choose “View Source”.

Comment: I get this [https://i.imgur.com/tI7j5tt.png](https://i.imgur.com/tI7j5tt.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something to break up the tag, so it's not interpreted by Razor as a tag to be processed. For example:

```
&lt;partial name="~/Breadcrumbs/BreadcrumbTemplate.cshtml" model="breadcrumbs" /&gt;
```

Comment: This will trigger a malicious script error! The correct answer would be the one provide by kalitsov.

Answer (score 5):

According to the MSDN link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1
you could

1. Disable the individual tag helper by prefixing with ! (exclamation mark)

   ```
   <!partial name="~/Breadcrumbs/BreadcrumbTemplate.cshtml" model="breadcrumbs" />
   ```
2. Remove a specific TagHelper from the view by specifing @removeTagHelper

   ```
   @removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
   ```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the simple the `<!` trick

Answer (score 0):

Removing the following from `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` should disable all tag default tag helpers.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Also from [How can i stop a Tag Helper automatically being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498990/how-can-i-stop-a-tag-helper-automatically-being-used): you can also use `@removeTagHelper` to remove a specific one, or prefix the helper with !, I.E. `<!partial>` to disable it in a specific instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498990/how-can-i-stop-a-tag-helper-automatically-being-used has additional and possibly better ways of doing this

Comment: Thanks, but I want only prevent rendering once, not all.